# How to change index of widget in float layout?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've got problem with indexes of images in Float Layout.

I need to put a pressable image (on_press event in ImageButton which inherits from Button and Image) on top of the layout (I mean in Z dimension) during the program.

Any ideas? I was trying to do this, but I didn't make it :/  Here is the FloatLayout in kivy code

```
FloatLayout:
    pos: 0, root.height*0.101
    spacing: 5

    ImageButton:
        id: mat
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        size: root.width * 0.5, self.parent.height * 0.89 * 0.5
        source: 'mat.png'
        pos: 0, root.height*0.11 + self.height

    ImageButton:
        id: geo
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        size: root.width * 0.5, self.parent.height* 0.89 * 0.3333
        source: 'geo.png'
        pos: root.width*0.5, root.height * 0.11
    ImageButton:
        id: human
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        size: root.width * 0.5, self.parent.height* 0.89 * 0.3333
        pos: root.width*0.5, root.height*0.11 + self.height
        source: 'human.png'
    ImageButton:
        id: biot
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        size: root.width * 0.5, self.parent.height* 0.89 * 0.3333
        pos: root.width*0.5, root.height*0.11 + 2*self.height
        source: 'biotech1.png'
    ImageButton:
        id: bio1
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        size: root.width * 0.5, self.parent.height* 0.89 * 0.5
        pos: 0, root.height*0.11
        source: 'bio1.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `remove_widget` and then `add_widget` with the index argument

```
self.remove_widget(w)
self.add_widget(w, 0) # first
... # or
self.add_widget(w, len(self.children)) # last...
```

You can also change `children` directly:

```
self.children.insert(self.children.pop(2), 0)
```